# Uploading a file using HTML PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm new to PHP, I picked up some sample code from internet, to upload a file to a server using the PHP script.

I'm trying to upload a file using the below code,

HTML code:

```
    This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>

    <form action="classes.php" method="post"><br>
        Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="upfile">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
 <?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');


try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here.
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
?>
```

While trying to upload a file, I'm getting "Invalid parameters." message.

Can anyone please help me to fix this.

Comment: add `var_dump($_FILES['upfile']['error'])`, see what the error is.

Comment: The form is missing **enctype** attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `enctype` in your code...

```
<form action="classes.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Do this, and it'll work fine...

Answer (score 1):

in your HTML you need the enctype

```
<form action="classes.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more details

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanks for your response. It works fine, but now I'm getting 'Failed to move uploaded file.' error. can anyone help me on this please ?

Comment: @padiyan If you are on Linux you need to give permissions on the path you want the files to move.Something like `chmod -R 775   yourpath`